# How to generate custom url in React TypeScript with Class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-typescript

I watched some stack overflow topic but they was always using function components. I want to know how can I generate custom url in TypeScript like http://localhost:3000/user/:userUid with Class Component.
I try this:

the path in Route is '/user/:userUID'

```
interface IURLInfo {
    userUID: string
}

interface IProps extends RouteComponentProps<IURLInfo> {

}

interface IState {

}

class ShipsBoyBoatDashboard extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        userIsLogged()

        firebaseAuth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if(user) {

            }
        })
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <div className="ship-dashboard-container">
                <p>{this.props.match.params.userUID}</p>
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default withRouter(ShipsBoyBoatDashboard)
```

But React send me back an error: TypeError: this.props.match is undefined

**UPDATE**
this is my index.tsx:

```
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './utils/history';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And my App.tsx (even it is useless)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import BaseLayout from './utils/baseLayout';
import routes from './routes';

export default class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showNavbar: true
  }

  showNavbar = (showNavbar = true) => {
    this.setState({ showNavbar });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BaseLayout showNavbar={this.state.showNavbar}>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map(route => (
            <Route
              exact
              key={route.path}
              path={route.path}
              render={() => (
                <route.component
                  showNavbar={() => this.showNavbar(route.showNavbar)}
                />
              )}
            />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </BaseLayout>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us the full code which you setup your router + your component from the import things? Since there is nothing wrong with your above snippet.

Comment: Okay @tmhao2005, it's done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your use of the `render` prop. See the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) here.

The function you pass to `render` takes the react-router injected route props (i.e. the `match` prop and others) as an argument, but you then need to manually pass those props through to the component you're rendering in the function. That doesn't happen automatically.

This is unlike using the `component` prop where the route props *are* automatically injected into the component by react-router - that might be what you've seen in other examples.

Try this

```
render={(routeProps) => ( // routeProps is an argument to the render function
  <route.component
    showNavbar={() => this.showNavbar(route.showNavbar)}
    {...routeProps} // you need to pass them through to the rendered component
  />
)}
```

Or, to demonstrate passing `match` more directly...

```
render={({ match }) => (
  <route.component
    showNavbar={() => this.showNavbar(route.showNavbar)}
    match={match}
  />
)}
```

Comment: Yuy it's like I didn't understand what you're trying to explain me

Comment: @Gregoirelpv sorry are you saying you *do* understand now, or something in my answer still doesn't make sense to you? :-)

Comment: Sorry something in yout answer still doesn't make sense to me

Comment: I gave a bit more detail on a couple of things - any specific questions though feel free to ask!

Comment: It works perfectly, the code did not work because of a small error on my part which no longer made your code snippet work